# Delay loading dll in release mode

Tags: c, visual-studio, matlab, dll, matlab-engine

In a C project i'm building in Visual Studio (C++ 2010 Express), I use the MatLab engine to allow for a user to provide a custom function to use within the project. The problem is that this code also needs to be able to run on computers without MatLab installed on it, meaning that the required DLL's will not be available on the computer in that case. Of course this should only work when the user does not try to access the piece of code which calls the matlab engine (I have provided a flag for this).

I have 3 dll's that are needed for this scenario.

- **libmx.dll**
- **libmex.dll**
- **libeng.dll**

So far i have been able to load the libeng.dll at run-time using **LoadLibrary** and **GetProcAddress**.
The other two DLL's are a bit harder though, apart from the C-code calling the MatLab engine, the code is also often compiled as a mex-file (MatLab executable), to allow users to call it from MatLab. When compiling as a mex-file, both libmx.dll and libmex.dll are dynamically linked by the mex compiler. This means that using **LoadLibrary** and **GetProcAddress** don't work for these DLL's.

Right now I just add the libmx and libmex LIB's to the linker properties in visual studio and this works fine, but will not be possible for someone who doesn't have MatLab installed.

I have tried using **delayLoad** and this works if I compile in Debug mode, but gives this build error when I compile in release mode.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win32\libmx.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B8
```

Is there a way to just completely skip looking for / Loading these DLL's if the part of the code that uses them is not accessed?

This is the command line for the linker:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\A.Vandenber\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Flash\Release\Flash.exe" /NOLOGO "C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win32\libmx.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win32\libmex.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DELAYLOAD:"libmex.dll" /DELAYLOAD:"libmx.dll" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Release\Flash.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\A.Vandenber\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Flash\Release\Flash.pdb" /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PGD:"C:\Users\A.Vandenber\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Flash\Release\Flash.pgd" /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

Comment: What options did you set to the linker? Note that you don't add the *.dlls* to the linker properties, but their corresponding *.lib*s.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I did ad the *.libs* and not the *.dlls* to the **properties->linker->input -> additional dependencies** and then the *.dlls* to the **properties->linker->input->Delay Loaded DLL's**

Comment: In the *Release* config didn't you forget to specify */DELAYLOAD* in front of one of the *.dll*s? Or didn't you try to build for *x64*? Paste the linker command in the question.

Comment: I added the linker command. It is 32 bit. I had some trouble getting it to work for x64 with Visual C++ express 2010 and apparently that is a common issue

Comment: Did you rebuild your solution? Cause the error makes no sense in the current context. Or, rebuild and post the full error. Are you using some custom build steps as well?

Comment: I'm glad you agree that it doesn't make sense :) But yes i rebuilt. There are some warnings (nothing interesting) and one error message, which is the one in my answer. No custom build steps.. I should add, it works if i add the directory where the libs are located to my PATH environment variable, but the goal is to be able to compile it without the lib files.

Comment: I get why you want to be able to use your project without Matlab, but why do you need to be able to compile without those lib files?

Comment: oh wait, so I guess if you compile with the lib files and add the dll's to DelayLoad, you can run it without them? That actually would make so much sense.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-engine.html) : "Using the MATLAB engine requires an installed version of MATLAB; you cannot run the MATLAB engine on a machine that only has the MATLAB Runtime." . You may need to use [MATLAB Compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html) that only requires installation of [MATLAB Runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html) on the destination machines.

Comment: @rahnema1, the goal is to be able to run the program without MatLab, provided that the user then doesn't turn the option for using it on. The DLL for the matlab engine is loaded at runtime. so if the flag is turned off, it is never loaded.

Comment: Which flag do you mean?

Comment: @rahnema1 a flag in the input for the code which determines whether the part with the matlab engine is entered or not. If it's turned off, the LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to load the matlab engine DLL is not used.

Comment: Any way to **freely** reproduce the environment? I (shallowly) searched for *Matlab* products, but couldn't find free ones.

Comment: I know that Octave is a popular free alternative to Matlab but i assume that the similarities will not reach as far as the C API. However, it turned out to be a bit of a non-issue. The version that is distributed to the users will be using matlab runtime environment, the C code will be compiled as a mex file, including libmx and libmex, which means they will be able to run the code with no issues.

Comment: Can you split the "features requiring MATLAB" into a separate DLL, which links to the MATLAB libraries normally, and then delay-load (or explicit-load with `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`) your feature DLL into the main program?

Comment: Is it reproducible on other computers? Or on different *VStudio* versions? But are you sure that those *.lib* files are actually lib files? Because their location seems strange (in the *bin* dir). What is the linker command in Debug mode?

Comment: Could you post some minimal code that reproduces the problem? I have now installed version *2012b*, i do have the 3 *.dll*s, but i don't have the corresponding *.lib*s. nor they were in *2012a.* I can see the 3 *.lib*s in *2014a*.

Comment: I realize now that the location i gave earlier was wrong, they are in extern/lib/win64/microsoft. The problem is solved however, so no need to worry about it any longer. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more I think about this, the more it looks like a [[Wikipedia]: **XY problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

### 1. The *X* (running the *MEX* file on a machine with no *MATLAB* libraries)

According to [[MathWorks]: Run MEX File You Receive from Someone Else](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/before-you-run-a-mex-file.html) (**emphases** are mine):

> **On Windows® platforms, install the C++ compiler run-time libraries used to create the MEX file**.
>
> ...
>
> A MEX file is a *dynamically linked* subroutine that the MATLAB interpreter loads and executes when you call the function. Dynamic linking means that when you call the function, the program looks for dependent libraries. MEX files use MATLAB run-time libraries and language-specific libraries. A MEX file might also use specialized run-time libraries. The code for these libraries is not included in the MEX file; **the libraries must be present on your computer when you run the MEX file**.

[[MathWorks]: MATLAB Runtime](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html) contains links for downloading many versions (**yours** - according to your paths - would be [[MathWorks]: MCR Runtime - MCR_R2012a_win32_installer.exe](http://ssd.mathworks.com/supportfiles/MCR_Runtime/R2012a/MCR_R2012a_win32_installer.exe)), which are **free** (I installed 3 of those versions to test this scenario), and also states:

> *Run compiled MATLAB applications or components without installing MATLAB*

So, it's pretty clear (to me) that whoever would like to use that file, should install the *MCR*.

### 2. The *Y* (using *Delay Loaded DLL*s)

*VStudio* supports this feature ([[MS.Docs]: Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls)) for quite some time.

Never worked with *MEX* files, nor do I have the full problem specs, but allowing one such file to run when there are no *MATLAB* *.dll*s present, doesn't look like good design to me (meaning that it also contains other stuff - which on my opinion should be placed separately). The only scenario that makes sense is that the *MEX* file would be an *.exe* (don't know whether this is possible or it's just a dumb thing) and it would have some `--help` equivalent (which would be nice (but **not** mandatory) to run on environments without the *.dll*'s). 
But that too could be solved using other ways (e.g. a *README* like file)

### 3. The end problem

Considering that there were / are multiple (logical) errors in the question:

- The *.dll*s passed to the linker
- The *.lib* files located in the *bin* dir
- The latest path (*extern/lib/win64/microsoft*) contains *64 bit* *.lib*s, while the linker is set for *32 bit* output
- [[MS.Docs]: Linker Tools Error LNK1107](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1107) which is pretty clear (as the error message in the question)

I can only conclude that for *Release*, "*C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win32\libmx.**dll***" **was incorrectly fed to the linker** (instead of the corresponding *.lib*).

I played a little bit with *MEX*:

*code.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <mex.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Argument passed: mexEvalString() returns\n", mexEvalString("n = 1;"));
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Argument NOT passed: pass...\n");
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Press a key to exit...\n");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- I used *fprintf* because in *mex.h* there is a line:

  ```c
  #define printf mexPrintf
  ```
- Didn't know what function to use from *libmx.dll*, to force it being added directly (not just a dependency for *libmex.dll*)
- I was able to test the *Delay Laded DLLs* feature in *Debug* **and** *Release* (when passing no arg, the program ran without adding the *MEX* *.dll*s to *%PATH%*). 
  It's true that at runtime I got *Access Violation*, but that's a totally different issue
- Needless to say that adding any of the *.dll*s to "*Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies*", **triggered the exact same error**

At the end, I would like to mention that *MCR R2012a* (and some others that were released after it), are built with *VStudio **9.0** (2008)*, and building your program with *VStudio 10.0 (2010)*, will yield having both *CRT Lib*s in loaded your process, and in some cases that might trigger some errors (especially since *VStudio 9.0*'s comes as an *assembly*). 
This applies to *libmx.dll* and *libmex.dll*, but not *libeng.dll*.

Comment: I agree with my question being incorrectly formulated in quite some places. I am very new to dll's and making matlab call C, calling Matlab was just messing with my mind in all kinds of ways. Thank you for an elaborate answer to a bad question. I no longer have any problems with it, since the version that will be sent to users is compiled with matlab compiler for matlab runtime, using a mex file of our C-code. When compiling a mex file, the two libraries i had trouble with are automatically included. only the matlab engine will not be available to them, but that's loaded at runtime.

Comment: Not a bad question at all! Anyway, I find it a bit strange that *libeng.dll* is not included, while the other 2 are, as all 3 of them are installed by *MCR*. But hey, I am just as new to *MATLAB*.

Comment: hmm, running matlab engine applications require an installed version of matlab, not just the matlab runtime ([source](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-programs-1.html)) so even if they are included, it will not be able to start the matlab engine anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now I see *MCR*'s *libeng.dll* only has 11kb, and only exposes 17 functions, so it must be some kind of a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

First, move your code to the directory that has `access privileges` and not `read-only`. also check this answer here: [Delay load DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064910/delay-load-dll?rq=1)

To add the  `dll` files to  Visual Studio, You can follow this [Linking dll in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845886/linking-dll-in-visual-studio)

Another suggestion is to put the `dll` in the `c:\windows\system32`. When a program runs, it will search for this file in the `c:\windows\system32` directory. Before that, it will search the directory from which the program was run. Visual Studio runs programs from the directory of their project (where the mentioned .dll file should be put if it is not placed in the `windows\system32` directory). Similarly, if the program's executable file is run manually from its directory, the said .dll file should be in the `same folder where the program's executable` file is located. You will need administrator privileges to do that.